# C# send images over socket as fast as possible

Tags: c#, image, sockets, stream

I'm trying to send as fast as possible images over socket tried to compress... compare the images... it's still working pretty slow...
btw I tried to save the image before and after the compression and size was the same.... 1 or 2 kb les...

have a look in client side code:

```
    Bitmap pre;
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pre = GetDesktopImage();

        prev = Compress(ImageToByte(pre)).Length;
        theThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startSend));

        theThread.Start();
    }

    Bitmap curr;
    byte[] compressed;

    private void startSend()
    {
        sck = client.Client;
        s = new NetworkStream(sck);

        while (true)
        {
            curr = GetDesktopImage();

            compressed = Compress(ImageToByte(curr));

            if (Math.Abs(compressed.Length - prev) > 500)
            {
                bFormat.Serialize(s, compressed);

                prev = compressed.Length;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

compression methods:

```
byte[] Compress(byte[] b)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream z = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                z.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    }
```

and this is the server side:

```
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                bFormat = new BinaryFormatter();

                inBytes = bFormat.Deserialize(stream) as byte[];
                inImage = ByteToImage(Decompress(inBytes));

                theImage.Image = (Image)inImage;
                count++;
                label1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = count.ToString()));

            }
            catch { }
        }
```

btw I've seen some people who used socket.send and didn't save the image to stream.... may u guys explain the difference? and suggest me what wrong in my code and how can I improve my algorithm?

Comment: What is `GetDesktopImage`? What file format is the image? How big are the images? Looks like you are trying to make some kind of VNC?

Comment: not actualy vnc haha but if u say... i used  the capture image  algorithm [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3024/Capturing-the-Screen-Image-in-C) it just faster than graphics copy from screen and less cpu used... i think the format it take a screen shot of is memory bmp... whole screen size

Comment: Since both images are being generated on the client, why not compare them there and just send the differences to the server? It would off-load the server, especially in a multi-client application where you have many clients sending screenshots to the server.

Comment: I compare them bro then I send the image only If their are difference. ..look at the code @Ron Beyer

Comment: The code you have shown above doesn't do any comparison, so not sure how I'm supposed to realize that? And I'm not talking about sending the image only if something changed, I'm talking about *only sending the **changes** of the image*, which is a much smaller set of data.

Comment: In the code I just compare the image to bytes and if the current image byte was  bigger than the prev I send. It works very good I also used once in comparison algorithms memcmp. .etc but anyway it works better but what the hell u mean by sending the changes. ? Btw thank u for helping me bro

Comment: Ok, so an image can change and be smaller (think of a screen going from normal to mostly black, the black gets RLE encoded and ends up smaller).  Also, a screen can change in a way that both are exactly the same (think of a mouse pointer moving on a single color, the size won't change but the image will). What I mean is actually comparing, byte-by-byte, and sending the list of what bytes have changed.

Comment: I have no idea how could it be done in code. .. I would thank you if u could post post a sample here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really pushing the limits in terms of "too broad" as a close reason. The general problem of sending image data over a network is a very broad area of research, with a large number of different techniques, the specific application/user-scenario determining which technique is actually best.

That said, there is one very obvious change you can make to you code that is needed, and which *might* speed it up, depending on where the bottleneck is.

Specifically, you are using `ImageConverter.ConvertTo()` to convert the `Bitmap` object to a `byte[]`, and then you are using `GzipStream` to compress that array of bytes. The problem with this is that `ConvertTo()` is already compressing the data; the `byte[]` it returns contains the original bitmap represented as PNG format, which is a fairly good, lossless compression algorithm for images.

So not only does compressing it again accomplish practically nothing, it costs you a lot of CPU to do that nothing. Don't do that. Just send the `byte[]` data as-is, without running it through `GzipStream`.

Now, all that said…

As I mentioned, whether that change will really help all that much depends on other things, including how large the bitmaps are, and how fast the network you are using is. If you are already saturating the network even with the inefficient code you posted in your question, then speeding that code up isn't going to help.

Techniques that are used to deal with network bandwidth as a bottleneck include (but are not limited to):

1. Using lossy compression (e.g. JPEG, MPEG, etc.), and so simply discarding information that costs too much to send.
2. Using a differential compression technique (e.g. MPEG, MP4, Quicktime, etc.), which takes advantage of the fact that when dealing with motion picture video, most of the pixels from one frame to the next are unchanged or at least are very similar.
3. Sending rendering commands instead of bitmap data. This is commonly used for things like VNC or Microsoft's Remote Desktop/Terminal Server APIs, and takes advantage of the fact that on-screen drawing is very commonly affecting a large number of pixels using relatively simple drawing commands (filling/outlining rectangles, drawing text, painting small bitmaps, etc.).

In many cases, these techniques are combined in varying ways to achieve maximum performance.

If you want to use these kinds of techniques, you need to do a bit more than just asking a question on Stack Overflow. It is well beyond the scope of this site to provide broad documentation and tutorials on those techniques. You'll need to research them yourself, or even better just use existing implementations to achieve your goals.

Comment: thank u very very much bro i appriciate ur explaintion @Peter Duniho   so  about what u said about the  `ImageConverter.ConvertTo()` i should not use the compress method with the gzipstream? so to send it just use            `compressed = (ImageToByte(curr)); `?but i just notice it's less kb if i also use the compress.. dont ask me how i just saved the both files and there is a little diffrence... maybe cuz it was diffrent screens haha

Comment: Yes, just use the result of `ImageToByte()`. PNG has a variety of compression options and `ImageConverter` just uses default values. So it's plausible you'd see a small reduction in data size compressing it again, since you haven't optimized the PNG compression. But these reductions aren't likely to be large (less than 5-10% improvement in size I'd guess), and are costly to obtain. You'd be better off getting a PNG implementation that offers more control over compression and just optimizing the initial PNG compression, if you really need that.