# Sending images through sockets

Tags: sockets, networking

I have an idea for a client-server. The client handles only input, sending it to the server. Server handles the input, logic and then sends the image of the program to the client. The client prints the image on user's screen. Uses udp, slight artefacts in the image are tolerated.

How fast can those images travel through the Internet? Can they travel at least 5 times a second? I don't have 2 computers at hand to test it.

EDIT: One more question - how reliable is UDP protocol? How many pixels would arrive corrupted? Say, 10% on average?

EDIT2: For example, I have an 320x200 32 bit image (red,green,blue + alpha). That's ~2 million bits. How long it takes for the image to arrive from the server to the client, if my ping is X, my uploading speed Y Mbps and my download speed Z Mbps?

Comment: Up voted because I had the same problem but, what is the exact purpose of the host - client connection?

Comment: Also check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014732/c-sharp-send-images-over-socket-as-fast-as-posibble. I know it's in C# but it has a lot of helpful info

Comment: Thanks. I have this idea of a platform-independent application. The server can be written with one machine/operating system in mind while the client is such bare-bones that it can be quickly written for any architecture. It uses very little resources, so the application's speed is bound not by processing power but by the internet connection. I gyess it's very impractical, but who knows.

Comment: You get (1/pingInSeconds) roundtrips per second.

Comment: The question is seriously underspecified.  What kind of images are we talking about? Size, compression, data size? What bandwidth can we assume for _”the internet”_ here?

Comment: usr: thanks. Not want to come off as an idiot but.. how do I measure this ping thing? :P

Comment: ping uses icmp protocol and you are trying to estimate the speed of iimage with udp protocol. first calculate the throughput of the network. If you send x number of bits/s how many of them are received ( see iperf, its tool to send dummy udp traffic). Wrt to stats you received match it for your image.

Answer (score 3):

The answers to your questions depend heavily on the internet connections of the machines involved.  In particular, if the program is heavily graphical, the bandwidth used by the images may be fairly substantial, especially if your client is on a mobile device connecting through the cellular telephony system.

If you have plenty of bandwidth, 5 round trips per second should be achievable most of the time if both client and server are in the U.S., or both are in Europe.  There are, for example, interactive computer games that depend on having 4-5 round trips per second for smooth play, and only occasionally have glitches as a result.  If client and server are on different continents, and especially if they are on opposite sides of the world, this may be more difficult, as speed of light delays start using a significant proportion of the available transmission time.  In the worst case, say between China and Argentina, theoretical speed of light delays alone limit the network to less than 8 round trips per second, so with real network and bandwidth limitations, 5 round trips per second could be difficult to achieve.

The reliability of UDP depends substantially on how congested the connection is.  On an uncongested network connection, you'd probably lose 1% of the packets or less.  On a very congested network connection, it might be a lot worse - I've seen situations where 80% of the packets were lost.

On an uncongested network, the time for an image to travel from the server to the client would be

```
(ping time)/2 + (1-packet overhead)*(image size)/(minimum bandwidth)
```

Packet overhead is only a few percent, so you might be able to drop that term out.  Minimum bandwidth would be the minimum of the server upload bandwidth and the client download bandwidth.  Note that the image size might be reduced substantially through compression.  Don't forget, though, that you also need to allow for time for the input to be sent from the client to the server, which adds another (ping time)/2 at a minimum.